# Roundtrip leading 0s of hexadecimal numbers

Tags: python, yaml, ruamel.yaml

I'm willing to load a yaml file containing 32-bit hexadecimal numbers, and keep the leading 0s so that the number is always in the form 0xXXXXXXXX.

I have created a custom class and representer so that dumping hexadecimal numbers in this form is possible:

```
class HexWInt(int):
    pass    

def represent_HexWInt(self, data):
    # type: (Any) -> Any
    return self.represent_scalar(u'tag:yaml.org,2002:int', '0x' + format(data, 'x').upper().zfill(8))

yaml.RoundTripRepresenter.add_representer(HexWInt, represent_HexWInt)
```

However, I cannot find a proper way to apply this format to roundtripped hexadecimal numbers.

Indeed, the following:

```
yamltext = "hexa: 0x0123ABCD"
code = yaml.round_trip_load(yamltext)
yaml.dump(code, sys.stdout, Dumper=yaml.RoundTripDumper)
```

Displays

```
hexa: 0x123ABCD
```

Where I would like this to be displayed

```
hexa: 0x0123ABCD
```

How can I proceed to force hexadecimal numbers to fit the 0xXXXXXXXX format?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are multiple ways to do what you want. If you don't want to influence the normal behaviour for the parser, you should subclass the `RoundTripLoader` and `RoundTripConstructor` with alternative `RoundTripConstructor` and `RoundTripRepresenter`. But that requires registering all constructors and representers, and is quite verbose.

If you don't care about being to be able to load other YAML documents with hex scalar integers that have leading zeros *with the original functionality* later on in your program, you can just add a new constructor and representer to the `RoundTripConstructor` and `RoundTripRepresenter`.

The easiest part is to get your format, based on a value and a width. You don't need `zfill()` nor `upper()` for that if you are using `format` anyway:

```
'0x{:0{}X}'.format(value, width)
```

[does the job](https://docs.python.org/3.1/library/string.html#format-string-syntax).

The main reason that your code doesn't work is because your code never constructs a `HexWInt`, as the `RoundTripLoader` doesn't know that it should do so. I would also not hard code the width to eight, but derive it from the input (using `len()`), and preserve that.

```
import sys
import ruamel.yaml

class HexWInt(ruamel.yaml.scalarint.ScalarInt):
    def __new__(cls, value, width):
        x = ruamel.yaml.scalarint.ScalarInt.__new__(cls, value)
        x._width = width   # keep the original width
        return x

    def __isub__(self, a):
        return HexWInt(self - a, self._width)

def alt_construct_yaml_int(constructor, node):
    # check for 0x0 starting hex integers
    value_s = ruamel.yaml.compat.to_str(constructor.construct_scalar(node))
    if not value_s.startswith('0x0'):
        return constructor.construct_yaml_int(node)
    return HexWInt(int(value_s[2:], 16), len(value_s[2:]))

ruamel.yaml.constructor.RoundTripConstructor.add_constructor(
    u'tag:yaml.org,2002:int', alt_construct_yaml_int)

def represent_hexw_int(representer, data):
    return representer.represent_scalar(u'tag:yaml.org,2002:int',
                                        '0x{:0{}X}'.format(data, data._width))

ruamel.yaml.representer.RoundTripRepresenter.add_representer(HexWInt, represent_hexw_int)

yaml_text = """\
hexa: 0x0123ABCD
hexb: 0x02AD
"""
yaml = ruamel.yaml.YAML()
data = yaml.load(yaml_text)
data['hexc'] = HexWInt(0xa1, 8)
data['hexb'] -= 3
yaml.dump(data, sys.stdout)
```

`HexWInt` stores both value and width. `alt_construct_yaml_int` passes everything to the original `construct_yaml_int` except for the case where the scalar starts with `0x0`. It is registered with `add_constructor()` based on the normal regex based matching done by the Resolver. The representer combines the value and width back into a string. The output of the above is:

```
hexa: 0x0123ABCD
hexb: 0x02AD
hexc: 0x000000A1
```

Please note that you cannot do something like:

```
data['hexb'] -= 3
```

as `ScalarInt` (which does have the method `__isub__`) doesn't know about the width attribute. For the above to work, you'll have to implement the appropriate methods, like `ScalarInt` does, as methods on `HexWInt`. E.g.:

```
    def __isub__(self, a):
        return HexWInt(self - a, self._width)
```

---

An enhanced version of the above (which also preserves `_` in integers and supports octal and binary integers) is incorporated in `ruamel.yaml>=0.14.7`

Comment: Great, thank you!

Would it make sense to roundtrip tailing 0s of decimal numbers as well? It would help for instance for storing version numbers.

Comment: @noname120 I am not sure what you mean with decimal numbers. For any scalar that is interpreted as an integer (hex, octal, decimal, binary) the trailing zeros determine a different value and that value (and the zeros) is preserved. If you mean scalars that are floats, then just doing the zeros is not enough as the the whole interpretation (scientific notation, mantissa, signs) is currently lost and most programming languages have errors in representation of floats. Even for integers (in 0.14.7) the sign is dropped. Real decimals require IMO a tagged type to round-trip exact.

Comment: OK, thanks for your explanations. For a concrete example, with a roundtrip, [`firmware: 3.60`](https://github.com/vitasdk/vita-headers/blob/master/db.yml#L2) becomes `firmware: 3.6`. This is not a big annoyance, though.